# Timer loop displaying 0 ticks instead of 60

Tags: java, timer, nanotime

I have the following code:

```
public void run(){
    long lastTime=System.nanoTime();
    final double amountOfTicks=60.0;
    double ns=1000000000/amountOfTicks;
    double delta=0;
    int updates=0;
    int frames=0;
    long timer=System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(running){
        long now=System.nanoTime();
        delta+=(now-lastTime)-ns;
        lastTime=now;
        if(delta>=1){
            tick();
            updates++;
            delta--;
        }
        render();
        frames++;

        if((System.currentTimeMillis()-timer)>1000){
            timer+=1000;
            System.out.println(updates+" Ticks, FPS "+frames);
            updates=0;
            frames=0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}
```

This should display "60 Ticks, FPS 9000000", but instead it displays "0 Ticks, FPS 9000000".
Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked whether `updates` has been incremented once before printing it?

Comment: Your boolean parameter running is set outside of your provided code, so it's hard to now what ends your while loop. Did you remember to set it to true in the first place?

Comment: This is a textbook debugging problem. Just hook up a debugger and walk through the code to see what's going wrong.

Comment: The loop is working. I have a `start` method that I called in `main` that sets `running = true`. The tick and FPS counter displays at a constant rate in the console, so I'm sure it's working.

Comment: @devnull Why would `if(delta>=1)` be an issue?

Comment: @Insederec Best would be to step through a debugger.

Comment: Well how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing NetBeans for its debugger, I've found that delta was a negative number. As it turns out, it was a simple typographical error.

`delta+=(now-lastTime)-ns;` should be `delta+=(now-lastTime)/ns;`